# How to do two or more functions with one click of a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

It's my first time on here, and I've read the posting guidelines. Still, forgive me if I make any mistakes.

It's my very first time doing AS3 and Animate CC. I decided to do a project - one where you click on armor and the armor appears on the avatar. Much alike to a 'dress-up' game, but I don't want to drag at all. Basically, I want people to click on an armor image and then have it appear on the avatar wearing it. However, there are multiple armor options such as Shirt 1, Shirt 2, or Skin 1, Skin 2, etc. My main issue right now is that I can't figure out a way to have an item vanish once another item gets clicked, especially in the same category such as skins.
I've Googled a lot for two days now and there's no solution in sight. I've found codes such as reset, off-setting the image, and other stuff I can't even remember.

I'm extremely sure I'm doing this entirely wrong. Here's the code for Frame 4, where the main issue is. Keep in mind I used different codes in different sections of the main code for Frame 4 and now the code is totally messed up.

EDIT: Updated the coding as requested.

```
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    stop();

function addItem(item:MovieClip,xPos:Number,yPos:Number){
    trace(item);
    trace(avatar_mc);
    avatar_mc.addChild(item);
    item.x = xPos;
    item.y = yPos;
}

basic_skin_1_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemSelect1);

function itemSelect1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addItem(basicskin1_mc,25,40); {
    }
}

basic_skin_2_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemSelect2);

function itemSelect2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addItem(basicskin2_mc,25,40)
}
```

Comment: The only thing I'll say is yes, you have the wrong idea about functions.  A few good things here, but the main thing that stands out to me is that you have a function for reset1 and hideskin2 and hideskin3. This, as you've probably gathered, is very inefficient coding because what happens when you want to add a 4th or 5th skin?  You'd have to add all this extra code.  Then what happens if you have 12 skins and you want to change something about the hideskin function?  You'd have to change it 12 times!  You need to have a single function that accepts a variable saying which skin your hiding

Comment: All right, thanks for telling me this. What I'm looking for is to hide all skins but one. For example, I click on the pale skin and it shows up on the avatar, but I don't like it so I click on the tan skin. What happens at this point is that the pale skin doesn't go away unless clicked again on the pale skin button, not the other buttons. I hope I'm explaining this at least a bit clearly...

Comment: @Snowdeath This is not an answer but I suggest to avoid if(something.visible){something.visible = false;}else{something.visible = true;} You can do this just by using this code in place : **something.visible = !something.visible;**. This method is shorter in order to change the value of a Boolean.
For the answer, I agree with NealDavis

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but you should learn this and update your code before going any further.

All I am addressing here is how to make one function work for multiple scenarios or inputs. This is really one of the main purposes of using custom functions and it is going to make solving your problem at hand much simpler.

```
function addItem(item:MovieClip,xPos:Number,yPos:Number){
    characterImage.addChild(item);
    item.x = xPos;
    item.y = yPos;
}
```

Then you can call this function like this

```
addItem(basicskin3_mc,0,0);
```

and then use the same function to add a different skin:

```
addItem(basicskin2_mc,0,0);
```

but I simply passed it a different argument (basicskin2_mc).

But then I get the bright idea to have the old skin get removed when I add a new one. Well now I just have to alter that one function instead of trying to update all the functions for every skin type and every armor type etc.

Comment: All right, I've been toying around with my code and decided to try to start over. I just have one question... What do you put in `characterImage`?

Comment: characterImage is your character you're dressing up. Probably just a paper doll or mannequin or copy of your character. It could be a MovieClip or a Sprite. It is what you're adding the armor and skin to. Make sense?

Comment: I still don't understand how to place `addItem(basicskin2_mc,0,0);` to this code; `basic_skin_2_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK ???);`?

Comment: ??? could be a function called `itemSelect`. This function should then call the `addItem` function with the appropriate arguments passed to it

Comment: Like this?

`import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

function addItem(item:MovieClip,xPos:Number,yPos:Number){
 avatar_mc.addChild(item);
    item.x = xPos;
    item.y = yPos;
}

basic_skin_1_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemSelect1);

function itemSelect1(e:MouseEvent):void {
 addItem(basicskin1_mc,25,40);


}

basic_skin_2_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemSelect2);

function itemSelect2(e:MouseEvent):void {
 addItem(basicskin2_mc,25,40)
}`

I tested and it passed but when I clicked on the button, it throws a 1009 error.

Comment: I went into debugging mode because it wasn't saying the specific line. Apparently the problematic line is this one; `avatar_mc.addChild(item);`

Comment: Do you have an `avatar_mc` in your display list or on the stage?

Comment: To check I would do this inside you addItem function: `trace(item); trace(avatar_mc);` and see what that puts out before the 1009 error

Comment: Now it throws out a 1120 error on `trace(item);`. The full code is this: `basic_skin_1_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, itemSelect1);

function itemSelect1(e:MouseEvent):void {
 addItem(basicskin1_mc,25,40); {
  trace(item);
  trace(avatar_mc);
 }
}`

Comment: You put the trace statement in the wrong place. It goes in the `addItem` function just above the line that caused the 1009 error

Comment: Nothing changed, so I guess that's a no for having `avatar_mc` in the display list or the stage even though I **see** `avatar_mc`'s picture. They're on different layers though, is that the cause?

Comment: Can you edit your question by clicking on the edit button and post your current code?

Comment: have you given `avatar_mc` a "linkage" in the library?  Also you can just make sure to give your MC an instance name of avatar_mc.  If you're unsure, see this post:  http://coursesweb.net/actionscript/objects-library-as3

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I named the linkage to `avatar_mc` and named the instance name to `avatar_mc`. Is that what you wanted? I think I did something wrong because now it leads to a 1046 error that says, "Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: avatar_mc."

Comment: You just get that error when you click an item button? Or is that happening at compile time?

Comment: No, it happened at compile-time.

Comment: Search for "automatically declare stage instances"

Comment: Anyway sorry this hasn't helped that much. I don't normally work with MCs on the stage created in the IDE; I do it all programmatically.

Comment: Found it. It's on, I didn't turn it on myself.

Comment: Ah, that's all right. Should I just do it all programmatically? Is that possible in Animate CC, or should I just go to programs like GitHub or something?

Comment: @Snowdeath I don't know what you should do. I know people do it the way you are trying to do it, you just need to find the right question to google or to ask.

Comment: Yes you can do it all programmatically in animate cc